# sqlite3.OperationalError: unrecognized token: "\"

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

```
import sqlite3
con=sqlite3.connect("mydbmb")
con.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS LOGIN
                (ID         INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
                 NAME       TEXT NOT NULL,
                 ROLL       INT NOT NULL,
                 photo      BLOB NOT NULL,
                 phone      INTEGER NOT NULL,
                 father     TEXT NOT NULL,
                 PASS       TEXT NOT NULL);''')

with open("7.jpg", 'rb') as file:
    blobdata = file.read()

quer=f'''INSERT INTO LOGIN(NAME,ROLL,photo,phone,father,PASS) VALUES('ADMIN','000','{blobdata}','678642873','GHHGJH','ADMIN123')'''
con.execute(quer)
print("query executed succsessfully")

user_list()
con.close()
```

Comment: Could the contents of `blobdata` be the issue? Can you give an example of what `quer` is before it's passed to `con.execute`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using literal parameters values (i.e. putting the values in the query) is error prone and insecure (unless they are constant)

It is much better to use bound parameters :

```
quer = '''INSERT INTO LOGIN(NAME,ROLL,photo,phone,father,PASS) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)'''
con.execute(quer, ('ADMIN','000', blobdata,'678642873','GHHGJH','ADMIN123'))
print("query executed successfully")
```